# a first versus the first

Tags: articles

> When I come to I'm in thick brush, lying there on the damp ground like
>   some log. I can't see a thing, it's so dark.
>    My head propped up
>   by prickly brambles, I take a deep breath and smell plants, and dirt,
>   and, mixed in, a faint whiff of dog crap. I can see the night sky
>   through the tree branches. There's no moon or stars, but the sky is
>   strangely bright. The clouds act as a screen, reflecting all the light
>   from below. An ambulance wails off in the distance, grows closer, then
>   fades away. By listening closely, I can barely catch the rumble of
>   tires from traffic. I figure I must be in some corner of the
>   city.
>    I try to pull myself together and pick up the scattered
>   jigsaw puzzle pieces of me lying all around. ***This is a first***, I
>   think. Or is it? I had this feeling somewhere before. But when? I
>   search my memory, but that fragile thread snaps. I close my eyes and
>   let time pass by.
>    With a jolt of panic I remember my backpack.
>   Where could I have left it? No way can I lose it––everything I own's
>   inside. But how am I going to find it in the dark? I try to get to my
>   feet, but my fingers have lost all their strength. (Kafka on the
>   Shore, tr. by Philip Gabriel)

If the sentence were ‘this is the first’, I would not have raised my question. What does *a first* mean?